# Python data slicing

Tags: python

How am I supposed to get the row that meets two requirements?
In my dataset, I have `officer_id_hash` and `arrest_made`, I need to get the officer_id_hash while the arrest_made == 'True'.

I wrote the code:

```py
df['officer_id_hash'&'arrest_made' == 'True'].max()
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: Is it really the string "True", or is it a boolean column with the value True?

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
"It doesn't work" is not a problem specification.

Comment: We also expect that you will trace the suspect values just before the point of error. Where are you confused about how they got to those values?

Comment: Hello and welcome! I'm not really sure what you're trying to ask here. Could you give some sample code and data? Also be sure to use ` instead of ' when marking where your code is

Answer (score 0):

```py
df[df['arrest_made'] == True]['officer_id_hash']
```